# Appium Jenkins test execution freeze

Tags: android, jenkins, testng, adb, appium

Appium scheduled test (Jenkins) fails giving such log message :

```
project.CardManagementTest.setUp FAILED
    org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: An unknown server-side error occurred while processing the command. Original error: Cannot stop and clear com.ao.demo. Original error: Error executing adbExec. Original error: Command '/Users/administrator/Library/Android/sdk/platform-tools/adb -P 5037 -s emulator-5554 shell pm clear com.ao.demo' timed out after 20000ms{"stdout":"","stderr":"","code":null} (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information)
    Command duration or timeout: 212.78 seconds
    Build info: version: '2.53.1', revision: 'a36b8b1cd5757287168e54b817830adce*****', time: '2016-06-30 19:26:09'
    System info: host: 'macprobuild.corp.com', ip: '153.86,***.***', os.name: 'Mac OS X', os.arch: 'x86_64', os.version: '10.11.4', java.version: '1.8.0_73'
    Driver info: io.appium.java_client.android.AndroidDriver
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:422)
        at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorHandler.createThrowable(ErrorHandler.java:206)
        at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorHandler.throwIfResponseFailed(ErrorHandler.java:158)
        at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:678)
        at io.appium.java_client.DefaultGenericMobileDriver.execute(DefaultGenericMobileDriver.java:51)
        at io.appium.java_client.AppiumDriver.execute(AppiumDriver.java:1)
        at io.appium.java_client.android.AndroidDriver.execute(AndroidDriver.java:1)
        at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.startSession(RemoteWebDriver.java:249)
        at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.<init>(RemoteWebDriver.java:131)
        at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.<init>(RemoteWebDriver.java:144)
        at io.appium.java_client.DefaultGenericMobileDriver.<init>(DefaultGenericMobileDriver.java:47)
        at io.appium.java_client.AppiumDriver.<init>(AppiumDriver.java:114)
        at io.appium.java_client.AppiumDriver.<init>(AppiumDriver.java:132)
        at io.appium.java_client.android.AndroidDriver.<init>(AndroidDriver.java:97)
        at config.DesiredCapabilitiesSetup.startAppiumServer(DesiredCapabilitiesSetup.java:74)
        at foundation.CardManagementTest.setUp(CardManagementTest.java:44)
```

The strange thing that its executing when i`m in front of server machine. But if i  leave server machine for around 30 minutes and make build remotely it will fail.

Server machine have been configured to:
-prevent computer for sleeping automaticy.
-wake for network access
-Enable power nap.

On my local computer test runs and always give success result. 
On server machine there are some tests scheduled for other devices, but there are no actual devices connected to server machine via USB.
My test run on Emulator.

My Desired Capabilities are:

```
package config;

import com.***.moo.webcalls.AOEnvironment;
import com.***.moo.webcalls.AOWebClient;
import io.appium.java_client.AppiumDriver;
import io.appium.java_client.android.AndroidDriver;
import io.appium.java_client.android.AndroidElement;
import io.appium.java_client.remote.MobileCapabilityType;
import io.appium.java_client.remote.MobilePlatform;
import org.apache.commons.codec.binary.Base64;
import org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils;
import org.openqa.selenium.OutputType;
import org.openqa.selenium.remote.DesiredCapabilities;
import org.testng.annotations.BeforeClass;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.UUID;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;


public class DesiredCapabilitiesSetup {



    @BeforeClass


    public static AndroidDriver<AndroidElement> startAppiumServer() throws IOException {
// Taking App/Device/Link path from *txt file located in the project //
        /*
        String appLink = FileUtils.readFileToString(new File("appConfigurations/appLink.txt"));
        String deviceName = FileUtils.readFileToString(new File("appConfigurations/deviceName.txt"));
        String appName = FileUtils.readFileToString(new File("appConfigurations/appName.txt"));
        */
//                                                               //
        String appLink = FileUtils.readFileToString(new File("appConfigurations/appLink.txt"));
        String deviceName = FileUtils.readFileToString(new File("appConfigurations/deviceName.txt"));
        String appName = FileUtils.readFileToString(new File("appConfigurations/appName.txt"));



        DesiredCapabilities cap = new DesiredCapabilities();
        cap.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.PLATFORM_NAME, MobilePlatform.ANDROID);
        cap.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.DEVICE_NAME,deviceName);
        cap.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.VERSION,"6.0");
        cap.setCapability("avd","nexus");
        File appSource= new File(appLink);
        File app=new File(appSource, appName);
        cap.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.APP, app.getAbsolutePath());

        AndroidDriver<AndroidElement> driver = new AndroidDriver(new URL("http://127.0.0.1:4723/wd/hub"), cap);
        driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(80, TimeUnit.SECONDS);




        return driver;
    }



}
```

**Right now i  don`t understand from where this problem is coming from . It It Emulator or Adb or Jenkins or DesiredCap configurations.**

```
 org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: An unknown server-side error occurred while processing the command. Original error: Cannot stop and clear com.ao.demo. Original error: Error executing adbExec. Original error: Command '/Users/administrator/Library/Android/sdk/platform-tools/adb -P 5037 -s emulator-5554 shell pm clear com.ao.demo' timed out after 20000ms{"stdout":"","stderr":"","code":null} (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information)
    Command duration or timeout: 212.78 seconds
```

Set Up

```
@BeforeClass
    public void setUp() throws Exception {

        driver = DesiredCapabilitiesSetup.startAppiumServer();
        aoWebClient = DesiredCapabilitiesSetup.getAOWeb();


        LogIn logIn = new LogIn(driver,aoWebClient);
        logIn.logIn();
    }
```

Comment: If i connect real device Jenkins and Appium works great.
But with emulator i got those error messages.

Answer (score 0):

--avd is deprecated under appium capabilities.

```
public static AndroidDriver<WebElement> ANDROID_DRIVER; 
ANDROID_DRIVER = new AndroidDriver<WebElement>(serverAddress, capabilities);
```

I define ANDROID_DRIVER as global
Also, could you please paste CardManagementTest.setUp code?

Comment: i added set up to the description. 
It`s running totally fine on real device connected to server machine. 
But when i`t is configured to run the emulator it can successfully run 6 times in a row and after fail 2-3 times because of emulator issue. 
Maybe the issue happen because the emulator process is  not getting killed after each test suite execution?